# How can I install xgboost for tox?

Tags: python, xgboost, tox

XGBoost needs to be compiled. For Docker, I install it like this:

```
RUN git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git
WORKDIR xgboost
RUN ./build.sh && pip3 install -e python-package
```

How can I make sure it is available for `tox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option [`sitepackages=True`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-sitepackages=True|False) makes `tox` create virtual envs that have access to globally installed packages. It's an option of virtual env section or global `[testenv]` section. Also can be set with `--sitepackages` command line option. Example:

```
[tox]
minversion = 1.8
envlist = py{27,34,35,36}

# Base test environment settings
[testenv]
basepython =
    py27: {env:TOXPYTHON:python2.7}
    py34: {env:TOXPYTHON:python3.4}
    py35: {env:TOXPYTHON:python3.5}
    py36: {env:TOXPYTHON:python3.6}
sitepackages=True
```

Comment: I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost'` after adding this line. Could you add a complete `tox.ini`?

Comment: Added an example. Can you import `xgboost` in a global python after `pip3 install -e python-package`? BTW, why `install -e`, why not just `install`?